# How do I create a JLabel from variables? (ie both named and populated by variables)

Tags: java, variables, jlabel

Is there a way to create a `JLabel` from a variable?  For a simple example, I'll use a survey creator, where the first user creates an array of questions for the next user to answer with 1-5 ratings.  If I want the first user to be able to enter the number of questions they want instead of a pre-defined number, how could I implement the `JLabel` creation line of the following pseudocode?

`for(int enterQuestion < int finishedEntering enterQuestion++)`

(not a for loop - a single button action, but it will keepo going till a finished button is clicked)

take input from user (GUI, so taking input from a `JTextField`)

assign that input to questions[enterQuestions]

create `JLabel (questionLabel + enterQuestions) = new JLabel(questions[enterQuestions]);`

The rest of the program I'm having no trouble, but I can't figure out how to generate labelID like that when I'm not doing a for loop because it depends on buttonClick to make changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the responses in a set to remove duplicates, then iterate the set to create your labels. The "new question" button (not the finished button) would grab the contents of the text field, add them to the set, clear the field, and so on. The finished button action would be to iterate the set and use each entry to construct the JLabels:

```
Set<String> responses = new TreeSet<>();
.
.
newQuestionButton.addActionListener(ActionEvent evt)
{
    responses.add(userInputTextField.getText());
    userInputTextField.setText(""); //clear the field
}
.
.
.
finishedButton.addActionListener(ActionEvent evt)
{
    for(String question : responses)
    {
         add(new JLabel(question)); //or some variation, based on your layout.
    }
}
```

You could use a LinkedHashSet instead of TreeSet if you wanted to preserve the order in which the questions were entered. TreeSet will give sorted traversal instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look tonight to see if that does it.

Comment: The only piece there where I'm running into a problem is that the GUI that the last set of JLabels is for won't be created till this one is finished.  It's a submenu - First the SurveyMaker GUI will launch.  When they click an "Add Questions" button, this GUI will pop up.  When they are finished and close this GUI with the finished button, it should have those question entities ready to be used to build a SurveyGUI when the creator clicks a "Launch Survey" button.  That's when I need to make the labels, isn't it, just leaving them in the LinkedHashSet till then?

Comment: I would think this would do it, but NetBeans doesn't like the array value declaration in the for loop for the eqFinished buttonListener.  Probably because I'm not familiar with this type of for loop ;)       for(String questions : questionsEQ){
                        questions[questions]=questionsEQ<questions>;
                    }    where questions[] is an array sized at the number of questions entered, so at the start of building the survey I can do the loop converting the array to JLabels

Comment: The only question left here is if any of these fields can stay in existence after the enterquestions method (the GUI this is working inside) closes so they can be used by the surveyMaker GUI to build the survey GUI?  It's working now, the only remaining question doesn't go in this thread, its a layout manager question.

Answer (score 0):

What if you make an `ArrayList` of `JLabels` and then have the `JTextField` with the `JButton` and when you click the button, get the text of the text field and then add a new `JLabel` to the `ArrayList` with the text field text as the passing argument. At the beginning of the program, make a field that keeps track of how many questions. Then you can add it to the `JPanel`, sort of like this.

```
private int questionCount = 0;
private ArrayList questionLabelList;
public Survey()
{
    questionLabelList = new ArrayList();
    //instantiate the JTextField and JButton here along with adding the actionListener
}
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(textField.getText() != null)
        {
             questionCount++;
             questionLabelList.add(new JLabel(questionCount + ". " + textField.getText()));
             add(questionLabelList[questionCount - 1]);
             textField.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: I've considered that option,. and I can do it that way if I have to, but I'd rather let them keep entering questions till they can't think of any more rather than having to define how many first.  I want the user to enter each new question in the bottom, click new question, and have the content they just typed converted into a JLabel and added to the top part of the window.  right now II'm creating a string that does question+=JTextField.getText(); and populating a single label with the result, and its not working well.

Comment: maybe a JLabel array initialized to mayQuestions?  then when they are done and click finished, convert it to a new array sized to questionCount that runs a for loop to duplicate the array entries with values to a new array thats just the size needed? then I could do JLabel questionLabel[[questionNumber] possibly?

Comment: would this create a permanent set of labels I could use from the SurveyMakerGUI that calls this enterQuestions GUI to create the SurveyGUI?  If so and my current method isn't, then this will be added to my answer.

Comment: eqFinished.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                    questionCount=questionNumber;
                //    String[] questions = new String[questionCount];
                    JLabel[] surveyQuestion = new JLabel[questionCount];
                    for(String questions : questionsEQ){
                        showQuestionsPanel.add(new JLabel(questions));
                   }
            questionGUI.setVisible(false);
            questionGUI.dispose();
            });

Comment: except I need to store them somewhere instead of add them to a closing window, and the window to put them in hasn't been created yet.